# iPad show a view not inside Tabbar

Tags: ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am developing an `iPad` application.

My application is a `UITabBar` based application with 5 tabs.
Now my requirement is to show a view controller outside these 5 tabs.

**Explanation:**

For example I have 5 tabs, A, B, C, D, E.
A is selected by default.

Now I have to show a new view controller say, F. But when I show that view none of the tabbar item should be selected.

**What I have tried:**

I created a `UINavigationController` as 6th tab. Now its not visible at the bottom and it nearly produces the effect I needed but have following two problems.

1. Tab bar items are not center aligned (Due to one hidden tab at right)
2. User can tab that hidden tab

**Update:**

Actually I am following an already developed application and I am sure its possible.
Scenario is I have 5 tabs that user can access without login. On navigation bar I have login button. When user is logged in I have a menu button in my navigation bar. Now tapping menu will show a view that doesn't belongs any of the tabs below. And that's why I need implementation explained above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Work around I used to achieve above effect.**

When I need to push my new `UIViewController` for which I want to deselect all of the `UITabBarItem` of my tabBarController, first I do the following things

1. Set selected index of tabBarController to last tab.
2. Set deselected image in last `UITabBarItem`
3. Get navigation controller of last tab and pop it to `RootViewController`.
4. Now push my new controller
5. Hide back navigation button in my view controller.

Hence I am able to show a Viewcontroller keeping user experience as current view is not in any of the tabs.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a [modal view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html), i.e. one that's displayed in response to some user interaction other than selecting it via the tab bar.

Comment: But i have to retain my bottom tabs.

Comment: You'll have to tell us more about how one gets to this extra view, then.